# Неизвестная конструкция объект/json f({"a":"b"})

Tags: javascript, json

Пришлось разбираться в чужом javascript коде. Наткнулся на такого типа конструкцию
Имеет вид

```js
    name_construction({
    "param": "content"
    })
```

Это похоже и на JSON и на объект. Но как получить доступ к содержимому не знаю.

Ответ от команды 
**name_construction.length** = 1

А что-то типа **name_construction.param** или **name_construction["param"]** не работает

Comment: Мне это больше на функцию с названием `name_construction` похоже

Comment: Вызов **console.log(name_construction) == f c(a){g=[a]}**, а вызов
**console.log(name_construction()) == undefined***

Comment: А этот код вообще работает? Может быть такое что это просто часть кода который работал раньше и не убрали его.

Comment: Он работает, и моя задача найти где и как он исполняется. Это содержание отдельного файла, который подгружается при работе большого скрипта. Я не могу найти момент, где он вызывается, и как другая часть кода использует данные "content"

Answer (score 2):

Это просто вызов функции с передачей в нее обьекта, а `length` функции возвращает количество ожидаемых параметров.

`name_construction["param"] не работает` - не работает потому-что нету у функции свойства `param`

Пример :

```js
function a1(b) {};

function a2(b, c) {};

function a3(b, c, d) {};

console.log(a1.length);
console.log(a2.length);
console.log(a3.length);
```

Читать [ТУТ](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

А про обьекты "похожие" на `json`, скажу просто, js-обьекты впринципе очень похожи на `json`, а свойства обьявлять можно как в кавычках так и без них, как и обращаться к ним :

```js
var a = {
  "param": "content A"
};

var b = {
  param: "content B"
};

console.log('b["param"] = ', b["param"]);
console.log('b.param = ', b.param);

console.log('a["param"] = ', a["param"]);
console.log('a.param = ', a.param);
```

Читать например  [ТУТ](http://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Answer (score 1):

Это просто параметры, которые передаются функции в виде объекта...

Внутри функции используются так:

`function f(data){
    console.log(data.a)
 }`

А вызываются так:
`f({a:10})`

Их никак не получить снаружи, если в функции они не присваиваются глобальной переменной и не возвращаются...

Варианты решения:

**Первый вариант - возвращение значения**

```
function f(data){
    //Код функции
    return data;
}
//Получение данных:
f({a:123}).data // {a:123}
```

Прокатит только, если в функции нет return

**Второй вариант - присваивание глобальной переменной**
(если первый реализовать не получается)

```
var tempdata;
function f(data){
    tempdata = data;
    //Код функции
}
```

Теперь данные можно получить из переменной tempdata